# How to make a Role Based Access Control system like discord in node js

Tags: node.js, express, discord

just as the topic says, i wanted to make a role based system in node-js. I got inspired by the system there is in discord. Can anyone please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by using multiple tables helpers to make a graph an RBAC (Role Based Access Control) approach. This is an opinionated answer, so take a deep look, try it, and consider it.

Here the dbdiagram URL https://dbdiagram.io/d/5f5f2c007da1ea736e2dbe4c, I explain on the comment there